# Implementation of Future's isCompleted method?

Tags: scala, future, traits

In following code:

```
val sbtFile: Future[String] = Future{
  val f = Source.fromFile("build.sbt")
  try f.getLines.mkString("\n") finally f.close()
}
println(s"status: ${sbtFile.isCompleted}")
Thread.sleep(250)
println(s"status: ${sbtFile.isCompleted}")
println(s"value: ${sbtFile.value}")
```

Future trait has polling method:isCompleted. This method is being called in above code.

In trait Future,this method is:

```
abstract def isCompleted: Boolean
```

Also, there is an object,never,defined in Future companion object and it extends Future trait,and returns false for isCompleted.

I couldn't find any other implementation.

So, which concrete completion is being called here?

Comment: It's in [scala.concurrent.impl.Promise](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.5/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Promise.scala)

Comment: OK.got it.But aren't promises and futures two different things. Strange that Promise's implementation is used for Future.

Comment: In Scala a `Promise` is a special case of a `Future`, other languages use these terms differently.

Answer (score 1):

In IntelliJ, right click on the isCompleted in your code and then Go To > Implementations. One of the places displayed will be scala.concurrent.impl.Promise as @Antot mentioned in the comment:

```
 class DefaultPromise[T] extends AtomicReference[AnyRef](Nil) with Promise[T] {
// ...
   override final def isCompleted: Boolean = isCompleted0
// ...
}
```